# Can use Traditional Form Submitting After add Dynamically a HTML Control with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Just to clarify my doubts!

Can I submit a form using traditional way (HTML submit button) if I've added a html control (`input`, `dropdown`, etc.) after the page was loaded using jQuery?

Or the only way is submit all HTML Controls is using Ajax call like `$.post()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard get and post functionality will still work, no worries. No ajax needed.

Try the following code, it will add both inputs to the get request and they will show up in the url as usual.

```
<form id="form" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="htmlway" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").prepend("<input type='text' name='jqueryway'>");
  });
</script>
```